# Limit comparison test for complex series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $\sum_{k=1}^\infty z_k$ is a convergent series with complex valued terms. Suppose there is a sequence of nonzero complex numbers $w_k$ satisfying $\displaystyle\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}(z_k/w_k)=1.$ Is it then true that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty w_k$ is also convergent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, take
$$z_k = \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}} \quad \text{and} \quad w_k=\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}+\frac{1}{k}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any sort of limit comparison test for the complex series with maybe additional assumptions which does not use any absolute convergence criteria?

Comment: @CarlLincoln I don't think so. Comparison tests are really made for positive real series. When you have a complex series that doesn't converge absolutely, you have to think in other ways : for example, in some cases, manipulations such as Abel's summation by parts can be useful.

Comment: I was hoping to find a similar result.  In the above problem, let us say we in addition assume $arg{z_k}/arg{w_k}\rightarrow 1$, what would be a counter example?

Comment: @CarlLincoln The same counterexample works... since $z_k$ and $w_k$ share the same argument here (they have the same sign).